# Has "the SE Network" been changed to "the SO Network"?

Tags: discussion, terminology, site-name

Today as most of you did, I received an email entitled

> #### [Terms of Service and Privacy] What's new

In the last paragraph, I noticed this expression:

> Please read these updated terms and take your time to understand these changes. Your use of **Stack Overflow**'s Products and Services, including **the Stack Overflow Network**, is subject to these revised policies and terms.

From time to time I've learned that the company is named "Stack Exchange Inc." and the Network has been referred to as "the Stack Exchange Network". I expected that in the bold text, it should have been "Stack Exchange".

Did the Department of Renaming just come up working?

Comment: The company changed name not long ago: https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/ (but the network should still be the "Stack Exchange Network")

Comment: I got mail from SO, New York which is HQ and not from SE. I think they called it SO network instead of SE for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

The company name is still *Stack Exchange Inc.*. The brand name used is *Stack Overflow*. The *network of sites* is still named the *Stack Exchange Network*. See for example the footer on each page, the SE front page, etc.

I think the legal officer meant to say *the entire network of software*, not just the Q/A sites, but also Jobs, etc.

From the ToS:

> a set of related Internet sites **and other applications**

So, in English:

> The Stack Exchange network of sites, and Jobs, etc.